# Android auto-backup xml rules

Tags: android, backup

I'm developing app which requires user data to be backed up on use's Google Drive and should backed up while reinstalling. I'm able to achieve desired action upto SDk 31 but on Android version 12 and higher data isn't backed up.

**manifest.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/balance_sheet_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/balance_sheet_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerDetails"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Profiles"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Premium"
            android:exported="false" /> <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="3940256099942544~3347511713" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Amount"
            android:exported="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Details"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ProcessHolder"
            android:exported="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities=""<!-- removed to upload -->
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**backup_rules.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
   Sample backup rules file; uncomment and customize as necessary.
   See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup
   for details.
   Note: This file is ignored for devices older that API 31
   See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/backup-restore
-->
<full-backup-content>
    <!--
   <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
   <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="device.xml"/>
-->
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <include domain="database" path="."/>
</full-backup-content>
```

**data_extraction_rules.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
   Sample data extraction rules file; uncomment and customize as necessary.
   See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/backup-restore#xml-changes
   for details.
-->
<data-extraction-rules>

    <cloud-backup>
        <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
        <include domain="database" path="."/>
    </cloud-backup>

    <device-transfer>
        <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
        <include domain="database" path="."/>
    </device-transfer>

</data-extraction-rules>
```

I'm unable to figure what I'm missing, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Android 12 or higher

```
<data-extraction-rules>
<cloud-backup [disableIfNoEncryptionCapabilities="true|false"]>    
<include domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" |
"root"] path="string"/>
    
<exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" |
                        "root"] path="string"/>
  </cloud-backup>
  
<device-transfer>
  
    <include domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" |
                        "root"] path="string"/>
    <exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" |
                        "root"] path="string"/>
  </device-transfer>

</data-extraction-rules>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#xml-syntax-android-12